# A fraction proof problem

Tags: inequality, fractions

Known:
$$N=\frac{A+B}{A+C}$$
$$A>1$$
$$\frac{B}{C}>1$$
Does $N$ increase/decrease with respect to $A$ (In other words, will increase $A$ always decrease $N$?

Comment: Have you just tried plugging in some numbers to see what happens?

Comment: I would usually first try approaching these types of problems by considering $N$ to be a function of $A$, with $B$ and $C$ being constant, and then take the derivative of $N$ with respect to $A$.  The result being negative, 0 or positive for different values of $A$ should then answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

Assume both $B$ and $C$ are positive. Then $B/C>1$ implies $B>C$, so we can write $B=C+D$ for some $D>0$. Then:
$$N=\frac{A+B}{A+C}=\frac{A+C+D}{A+C}=1+\frac{D}{A+C},$$
which clearly decreases with respect to $A$ (since $C$ and $D$ are positive constants). Similarly, you can handle the other case, when both $B$ and $C$ are negative.